# PHP file doesn't execute code after connecting to a database

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, mamp

After I run my PHP code, hello1 is printed on the screen, but not hello2. I assume there's something wrong with my code for connect.

I can't find what's wrong with my code. Unfortunately to me my code seems correct even after going over it multiple times. How can I fix it?

BTW, I am running [MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP) on a [MacBook Air](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air).

```
<?php
    echo "hello1";
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost:8888", "Capstone", "", "capstone");
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

    echo "hello2";

    if (!$connect) {
        printf("Connection failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        die();
        echo "hello3";
    }
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST["Sign Up"]))
    {
        if (empty($_POST["Email"]) || empty($_POST["Password"]))
        {
            echo '<script> alert ("Both Feldsa are required)</script">';
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['Email'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['Password'];
            $_SESSION['Repeatpassword'] = $_POST['Repeatpassword'];
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
            $_SESSION['weight'] = $_POST['weight'];
            $_SESSION['feet'] = $_POST['feet'];
            $_SESSION['inches'] = $_POST['inches'];
            $_SESSION['age'] = $_POST['age'];
            $_SESSION['goal'] = $_POST['Goal'];

            // Escape all $_POST variables to protect against SQL injection
            $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $password = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
            $RepPassword = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['Repeatpassword'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

            $name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['name']);
            $Weight = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['weight']);
            $feet = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['feet']);
            $inches = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['inches']);
            $age = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['age']);
            $goal = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['goal']);
            $hash = $mysqli->escape_string(md5(rand(0, 1000)));

            // Check if user with that email already exists

            // We know user email exists if the rows returned are more than 0
            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email_Address='$email'") or die($mysqli->error);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                $_SESSION['message'] = 'User with this email already exists!';
            }
            else { // Email doesn't already exist in a database, proceed...

                // active is 0 by DEFAULT (no need to include it here)
                $sql = "INSERT INTO User (Email_Address, Password, Full Name, Weight, Feet, Inches, Age, Goal, hash) "
                        . "VALUES ('$email', 'password', 'name', 'Weight', 'feet', 'inches', 'age', 'goal', 'hash')";
            }
            if (! $mysqli->query($sql)
            {
                $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration successfully';
                echo $_SESSION['message'];

                header("location: loginaccount.html");
            }
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration failed!';
            echo $_SESSION['message'];
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST["Login"]))
    {
        $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['Email']);
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email_Address='$email'");
        if ($result->num_rows == 0) { //
            {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";
                echo $_SESSION['message'];
            }
            else {
                $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
                if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['Password'])) {
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $user['Email_Address'];
                    $_SESSION['name'] = $user['Full Name'];
                    $_SESSION['weight'] = $user['Weight '];

                    $_SESSION['feet'] = $user['Feet '];
                    $_SESSION['inches'] = $user['Inches '];
                    $_SESSION['age'] = $user['Age '];
                    $_SESSION['goal'] = $user['Goal '];
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['active'] = $user['Active'];
                    header("location: loginaccount.html");
                }
            }
            mysqli_close($connect);
            session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: For one; you didn't connect to your database. I'd start with using debugging tools such as php's error reporting and error checking on the database and query. You can then edit your post to contain the errors; you do have some and quite a few and I'd rather "you" fix your code, that way you'll know what to do and to not do next time.

Comment: thanks I will try to find my own lol but would you like to point out at least one mistake for now

Comment: Sure thing, and this being the first one from the top: You're declaring `$connect` as the connection variable, yet you then switch to `$mysqli`. The change's answer is in the former. You can then work your way down with error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and the error checking on the query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: I do not understand your  point, I am just storing the object the function returns after creating a connection to database to work with it later, please make sure you answer makes more sense now

Comment: look at the query; `$mysqli` and your connection is `$connect`.

Comment: you don't make sense which line are you talking about

Comment: this convo just triggered the chat comment. I can't keep going on like this and I don't want to chat about it. If you think your connection works and interacts with your query, then I don't know what else to tell you. I tried helping by giving you links to debug it, but you seem to want an instant solution here. (cont'd)....

Comment: ... What I expected you to do was to then log off after your saying thanks to me, to which you're welcome; was to then spend some research and time. Then if say after a couple of hours you still have problems, you can update your post to contain what you tried and what error messages you get back. If I'm still here, I can offer to help you then or possibly other members here.

Comment: I was not looking for an instant answer, it just seemed you were really interested to point out the mistake that I think I did not make and even when I asked you, you could not respond tome clearly. I just wanted to make sure I understand what's going on here, and please keep your expectations to yourself I sincerely apologize for being able to live upto your expectations

Comment: I was going to ad the error reporting thing yesterday night but it was too late and I forgot about it today lol thank you ford reminding me

Comment: For one, the posted code is unbalanced: there are 13 `{`s and 11 `}`s.

Comment: See also near `if ($result->num_rows == 0) {`. I don't think that is what you intend.

Comment: Near `if (! $mysqli->query($sql)` a right parenthesis (`)`) seems to be missing.

Comment: After the indentation was fixed, is the code still what was intended?

Comment: You should have a look at how to setup XDebug and use it with a step by step debugger (NetBeans, Webstorm etc...). You would find your issue easily and save countless hours.

Answer (score 1):

At the start of your script:

```
echo "hello1";
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost:8888", "Capstone", "", "capstone");
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

At line 3 here, you try and use $mysqli.  That variable doesn't exist.  You haven't declared it, so at that point, you are going to get a PHP runtime error when you try and reference the method of an object, which is in fact a non-existent variable.

It's actually worse than that, because you are mixing procedural mysqli with object oriented mysqli.  What you really need is this, but the obvious issue is that your mysqli connection variable is named `$connect`!

```
echo "hello1";
$connect = new mysqli("localhost:8888", "Capstone", "", "capstone");
$connect->set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: hi Thank you for your response, i am using php 7.2 so Mysqli function don't exist in this version only PDO or Mysqli_connect,  the reason why i am saving the server as a object is to use it later,I have also seen tutorials that use the function in an object oriented manner and it still worksbut thank you so much for your suggesiton I will try it did you happen to see any other mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that I suggested you use mysql_.  My example is using mysqli.  I simply pointed out  the mistake you made mixing mysqli procedural and object oriented code.

Comment: oh sorry didn't notice yuh I later on moved to  that this evening

Comment: No worries.   Assuming that this helped you fix your problem you can accept my answer.

Comment: my issue was with database not the code the code is fine, I did not Password is a MYSQL term so when I made it a column name it was giving me issue

Comment: I'm sure the code is fine now that you fixed the problems that were pointed out.  Your code has other bugs like this:  `$sql = "INSERT INTO User (Email_Address, Password, Full Name, Weight, Feet, Inches, Age, Goal, hash) " . "VALUES ('$email', 'password', 'name', 'Weight', 'feet', 'inches', 'age', 'goal', 'hash')";` It's disappointing you can't admit that.  FWIW you can get around the issue of using a reserved word for a column simply by using backtics around the column names.

Comment: Hi thank you for pointing out if I did not fix that it wouldn't run right? I fixed it but forgot to edit it here, I posted here immediately and continued to work on it on my own because I was running out of time, thanks for pointing out how i was not using the fcntions for the object I declared but I seriously just noticed you writing new mysqli which does not exist for 7 or higher php at least that's what I had found out,

Comment: My point is that you had/have a number of issues with your code. They all have to be fixed in order to have success.  There is nothing I put in my code that is not in php7.  The mysqli api can be used either procedurally or via OOP form.  Your original code mixed the 2 and would not work.  I fixed that and hopefully you did too.  There is often more than one way to fix a problem.  Fixing that can lead to finding other errors which you will have to fix as well.

Comment: HI I understand how it feels to help someone who is not helpful, I swear when I wrote that comment that I had no coding issue I was able to have everything run and do their job smoothly after fixing the database and code related to database issue and completely forgot about fixing functions for objects that i declared and the thing you last pointed out, I didn't do it purposely and didn't remember until you pointed out I hope you're less upset now and let me know please

Comment: No worries, the primary motivation for most people here is to help others, just as we have been helped ourselves over the years.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `try/catch` to find more about errors

```
try{
    echo "hello1";
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost:8888", "Capstone", "", "capstone");
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    echo "hello2";

}
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

P.S. - in `$mysqli->set_charset("utf-8");` `$mysqli` is not defined, use `$connect` here

Comment: thank you this really helped me fix some of the later portions but forgot to say thanks because i was in rush to submit it

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped